# Question about the proof of the Recursiontheorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Please have a look at the proof, first of all I don't understand the parts of the proof where one is refering to the Definition of G.

In the inductionbase one Claims that $(1,x)$ is an element of G

In the inductionstep we define $x_{n+1}:= f_n(x_1,..,x_n)$ and claim that $(n+1,x_{n+1})$ is also an element G. Can please someone explain me why these two assertions are true due to the Definition of G?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's about the existential proof

Comment: I would also like to no how the uniqueness is used of $(1,x_1),...,(n,x_n)$ in the inductionstep